# Does “money laundering” also mean raising funds illegally?

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

When I looked up what *money laundering* meant, the dictionary said it meant “concealing proceeds raised from illegitimate sources”. Does *money laundering* also mean “raising funds illegally”?

If not, what are some other words we can use to mean “raising funds illegally”?

Comment: There are lots of ways to illegally raise/obtain money - robbing banks (or anyone else with money), extortion, drug-dealing, counterfeiting, etc. The only word I can think of that distinguishes these activities from other ***crimes*** such as murder and rape is ***theft***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, laundering is a way of spending **ill-gotten gains** in a manner that prevents detection of the source of the funds. –

Comment: Rather it's *converting* ill-gotten gains into funds that seem to have a legitimate source

Comment: I agree that "converting" is involved; I used "spend" to refer to the  *financial transactions* which are designed to disguise the.source of the funds, and which typically involve purchases via "legit" proxies.

Comment: thanks!! Is there a single word that can have the meaning - "raising illegal funds"

Comment: @Francis: I suspect there isn't a single English word meaning exactly and only [illegal fundraising](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22illegal+fundraising%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl). The closest is probably ***fraud***, but that can cover other criminal deceptions that don't directly involve "funds, money".